# jQuery dialog prints HTML-Tags under Wordpress

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-ui, wp-localize-script

i need some help. I am using wp_localize_script in my Wordpres_Plugin. Inthe documentready-function i use this Code to bring the Message up:

```
$('#button-setup-league').click(function() 
{
$( "#dialog p" ).append('<span>'+wpslm_v_script_vars.delete_league+'</span>');
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ 
                modal: true
            }); 
});
```

The Situation is, that in Wordpress 3.4 it runs very well with no Problems.

But under Wordpress 3.2 there are all the HTML-Tags like `<strong>` or `<br />` in the Messagebox visible. If i look in the Sourcecode, everything looks very good.

WP 3.2 runs jQuery 1.4 and WP 3.4 runs jQuery 1.7. Does this maybe effect the outputs?

Any help is very appreeciated. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of a longshot, but maybe try something like this:

```
$('#button-setup-league').click(function() 
{
$( "#dialog p" ).html('<span>'+wpslm_v_script_vars.delete_league+'</span>');
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ 
                modal: true
            });
});
```

This, of course, requires "#dialog p" to be initially empty, or assumes that its contents can be replaced entirely. If not, maybe you can use the solution above but with a more specific selector (i.e. "#dialog p span.insert_after", or maybe $("#dialog p").last() or something; hard to say without actual code).